# Android: Refresh view problem

Tags: android, button, refresh

I am having a problem trying to refresh a View in an Android application. I have a button that have a image and what I need to do is to change the image when someone clicked the button.

Where is the problem? The image don't refresh until the activity finished proccessing the code. Any idea how I can refresh the image as soon as It execute the instruction

```
buttton1.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.f1));
```

Comment: Could you show us how you are processing the click event in the button, please? What you put is how you change the background on the button, and it seems to be OK, so maybe the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: Cristian, this is the click event code
ficha1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Button bot = (Button) findViewById(R.id.boton1);
                bot.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.f2));
                //ficha.setText(fichas.get("boton1").toString());
                controlJugada(fichas.get("boton1").toString(), bot);
            }
        });

Once controlJugada() is execute the backgroud is updated. I need the background to be update it first.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using the xml side and have the drawables as selectors as then the selectors will get chosen by the particular key/touch event to display the correct graphic..

Answer (score 0):

Try running your method that does your processing from a thread.

```
ficha1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
    public void onClick(View view) { 
        Button bot = (Button) findViewById(R.id.boton1); 
        bot.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.f2)); 
        //ficha.setText(fichas.get("boton1").toString()); 
        new Thread(
            new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    controlJugada(fichas.get("boton1").toString(), bot);
                }
            }
        ).start();
    } 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved a similar problem by putting the offending code in a post delayed handler with a zero delay.

```
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // code slowing things down here
        }
    }, 0);
```

Answer (score -1):

The first thing you do in the onclick listner is change the backgrount of the button

Comment: Yes I know, but the image don't change until all the code is proccessed